# C Assembly Code

Tags: c, assembly, x86, stack, inline-assembly

Here is some code I was given, but its the first time I've seen the function *asm*. I'm not too familiar with assembly. I was hoping someone could just explain what the *asm* function is doing.

```
/* stack.c */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned long int sp;


int cp(char *str)
{
    char buffer[12];
    asm("movl %%ebp, %0" : "=r" (sp));
    printf("$ebp is 0X%lx\n",sp);

    strcpy(buffer, str);

    printf("Buffer is at address %p\n",(void*)(&buffer));
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char str[517];
    FILE *badfile;

    badfile = fopen("badfile", "r");
    fread(str, sizeof(char), 517, badfile);
    cp(str);

    printf("Returned Properly\n");
    return 1;
}
```

Could someone just explain what the following does?

```
asm("movl %%ebp, %0" : "=r" (sp));
printf("$ebp is 0X%lx\n",sp);
```

Comment: Well, you could guess from the `printf` what it does ... it stores the value of the `ebp` register into your (misleadingly named) `sp` variable.

Comment: @Jester: It is not actually misleadingly named; `%ebp` should contain a copy of the caller’s `%esp`, so the routine is reporting the caller’s stack pointer.

Comment: You have no idea what `ebp` contains especially with optimization enabled that does not set it up as frame pointer. In any case, "caller's esp" is not the same as "esp" so it's still misleading. It's definitely not "current esp" that one would expect.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: `-fomit-frame-pointer` is enabled by default in gcc for x86 (32-bit and 64-bit for several years now), except with `-O0`.  (Yes, even at `-O1` or `-Og`).    https://godbolt.org/g/bm8V56

Comment: @Jester: **I** might not know what `ebp` contains, but the author of this code clearly intended something, and you have no idea what version of GCC they wrote it for or what options they compiled with. You can hypothesize they did not mean the stack pointer and that `sp` is wrong because they did not know what they were doing and that your current use of the current GCC should control the meaning, but I think that is a poor hypothesis compared to the hypothesis that the author used the common abbreviation “sp” for the stack pointer because they intended to provide the stack pointer.

Comment: So you admit that not even you know what the author intended ... it's unclear at best, misleading at worst. Also note that the single use of it is in the `printf` which actually says _"value of ebp"_ so no mention of "stack pointer". Anyway, that is really not the focus of the question :)

Comment: @PeterCordes: What knowledge do you have of the original author of this code and the version of GCC and the associated switches do you have? Do you really think it is likely that the code, which does fetch the saved value of the stack pointer in the System V ABI or equivalent, was not intended to fetch the saved value of the stack pointer?

Comment: @Jester: Yes, no mention of the stack pointer. Except, of course, its common abbreviation, sp.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: It looks like a buggy implementation of something similar to what the author intended, and which only works when compiled without optimization.  Failing with optimization enabled is very common for beginner / poorly-written inline asm.  The code doesn't use `sp` for anything, so IDK what exactly they hope it will be pointing to.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly why it's misleading! It reads `ebp` it **says** it's showing `ebp`, so why is it called `sp`? It's like writing `int apples = getOranges(); printf("Oranges = %d\n", apples);` It should be called `fp` which is a common abbreviation for frame pointer :)

Comment: @EricPostpischil: And BTW the i386 System V ABI does *not* require making stack frames with `%ebp`.  [The official document does show](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/intel386-psABI-1.1.pdf) an example of stack layout if you do use it (`Table 2.2: Stack Frame with Base Pointer`).  But it doesn't even give an example of the setup sequence, though.  In Table 2.3, it says *`%ebp`: callee-saved register;* optionally *used as frame pointer*.  The SysV ABI specifies the `.eh_frame` section as the official way to unwind the stack, not by following a saved-EBP linked list.

Comment: @Jester: It says it is showing `ebp` and is called `sp` because it is both. It is the caller’s stack pointer, retrieved from %ebp. This code clearly is not part of production code. It looks like something tutorial, intended to demonstrate to somebody learning about Intel assembly, among other things, that the caller’s stack pointer can be found in %ebp (in the System V ABI or equivalent).

Comment: @PeterCordes: You have not given any interpretation other than “this name is wrong and this code does not work in current GCC with default switches” as an alternative to the hypothesis that the the name is right and the code does work in an environment it was intended for. If code and the identifiers used in it have a valid interpretation in some reasonable environment, it is a superior hypothesis that the code and its identifiers are correct and intended for such an environment than that the code is wrong.

Comment: Note that if gcc is actually using a frame pointer, it will **not** be the "caller's esp" whatever you think that means! Given that the typical function prologue is `push ebp; mov ebp, esp` it's actually a copy of the callee's `esp` as it was after that `push`. The caller's `esp` is 4 or 8 bytes more (depending on whether you count the return address).

Comment: @EricPostpischil: `gcc -O0` is the default, and that's sufficient for this code to maybe do something for a tutorial or example.  But the point here is that it's *not* useful or safe in general.  Given that all we have is the code, without the tutorial or discussion of what it's trying to show, it makes sense to pick it apart and point out that it's bad, and in other contexts won't do what some tutorial says it does.  Regardless of `-fomit-frame-pointer` or not, I still agree with Jester that `sp` is a bad choice of variable name without any comments or anything to explain why it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

"asm" in this code is not a function, it is a gcc extension (also inherited by clang) that allows inlining assembly code. You can read about it here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.4.0/gcc/Using-Assembly-Language-with-C.html

Comment: ICC and all other compilers that support GNU C extensions support it with the same syntax.  Think of GNU C as a dialect of C, not necessarily as gcc-only things.

Answer (score 0):

```
asm("movl %%ebp, %0" : "=r" (sp));
```

This substitutes whatever the compiler is using to address sp for %0. It then becomes something like

```
MOVE EBP, sp
```

Be clear I mean something like this. If your environment prefixes _ to global variables, it could translate into

```
MOVE EBP, _sp
```

(Other substitutions are possible.) Thus it moves the value of the hardware EBP register into your C variable sp.

```
printf("$ebp is 0X%lx\n",sp);
```

This prints the value of sp which is the value of the EBP register.

Comment: This is AT&T syntax, so it would be `movl %ebp, sp`.  Except it won't move directly to memory, because the asm uses an `"=r"` constraint to require that that operand be a register.  From gcc7.2 (https://godbolt.org/g/Rp2WJ6), you get `movl %ebp, %eax` and then you get `movl    %eax, sp` (compiler-generated store to update the value in memory of the global variable.)